# Replacing substring with variables in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am currently figuring out how to do a bit more complex data migration in my database and whether it is even possible to do in SQL (not very experienced SQL developer myself).

Let's say that I store JSONs in one of my text columns in a Postgres table wtih roughly the following format:

```
{"type":"something","params":[{"value":"00de1be5-f75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf2333"}]}
```

Now, I would like to migrate the `value` part to a bit more complex format:

```
{"type":"something","params":[{"value":{"id":"00de1be5-f75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf2333","path":"/hardcoded/string"}}]}
```

Furthermore, I also need to reason whether the `value` contains a UUID pattern, and if not, use slightly different structure:

```
{"type":"something-else","params":[{"value":"not-id"}]} ---> {"type":"something-else","params":[{"value":{"value":"not-id","path":""}}]}
```

I know I can define a procedure and use `REGEX_REPLACE`: `REGEXP_REPLACE(source, pattern, replacement_string,[, flags])` but I have no idea how to approach the reasoning about whether the content contains ID or not. Could someone suggest at least some direction or hint how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb` function for extract data and change them. At the end you should extend data.

Sample data structure and query result: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=75b538d21ed84f99170ca0c27fdf2e98)

```sql
select
  (t.data::jsonb || jsonb_build_object(
    'params',
    jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_build_object(
        'value',
        case
          when e.value->>'value' ~* '^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$' then
                jsonb_build_object('id', e.value->>'value', 'path', '/hardcoded/string')
          else 
                jsonb_build_object('value', 'not-id', 'path', '')
        end
      )
    )
  ))::text
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data::jsonb->'params') e
group by t.data
```

---

PS:

If your table had `id` or unique field you can change `group by t.data` to do things like that:

```sql
select
  (t.data::jsonb || jsonb_build_object(
    'params',
    jsonb_agg(
      jsonb_build_object(
        'value',
        case
          when e.value->>'value' ~* '^[0-9A-F]{8}-[0-9A-F]{4}-4[0-9A-F]{3}-[89AB][0-9A-F]{3}-[0-9A-F]{12}$' then
                jsonb_build_object('id', e.value->>'value', 'path', '/hardcoded/string')
          else 
                jsonb_build_object('value', 'not-id', 'path', '')
        end
      )
    )
  ))::text
from
  test t
  cross join jsonb_array_elements(t.data::jsonb->'params') e
group by t.id
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. It did not occur to me, that I could leverage `jsonb` structure.

Comment: Sometimes, this `value` field can be hidden deep in a very complex JSON, is it possible to have some automated way of fixing all the occurences in one single field?

Answer (score 0):

To replace `value`s  at any depth, you can use a recursive `CTE` to run replacements for each value of a `value` key, using a conditional to check if the value is a UUID, and producing the proper JSON object accordingly:

```
with recursive cte(v, i, js) as (
   select (select array_to_json(array_agg(distinct t.i)) 
   from (select (regexp_matches(js, '"value":("[\w\-]+")', 'g'))[1] i) t), 0, js from (select '{"type":"something","params":[{"value":"00de1be5-f75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf2333"}, {"value":"sdfsa"}]}' js) t1
   union all
   select c.v, c.i+1, regexp_replace( 
         regexp_replace(c.js, regexp_replace((c.v -> c.i)::text, '[\\"]+', '', 'g'), 
           case when not ((c.v -> c.i)::text ~ '\w+\-\w+\-\w+\-\w+\-\w+') then 
              json_build_object('value', regexp_replace((c.v -> c.i)::text, '[\\"]+', '', 'g'), 'path', '')::text 
           else json_build_object('id', regexp_replace((c.v -> c.i)::text, '[\\"]+', '', 'g'), 'path', '/hardcoded/path')::text end, 'g'), 
         '(")(?=\{)|(?<=\})(")', '', 'g')
   from cte c where c.i < json_array_length(c.v)
)
select js from cte order by i desc limit 1
```

Output:

```
{"type":"something","params":[{"value":{"id" : "00de1be5-f75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf2333", "path" : "/hardcoded/path"}}, {"value":{"value" : "sdfsa", "path" : ""}}]}
```

On a more complex JSON input string:

```
{"type":"something","params":[{"value":"00de1be5-f75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf2333"}, {"value":"sdfsa"}, {"more":[{"additional":[{"value":"00f41be5-g75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf3777"}]}]}]}
```

Output:

```
{"type":"something","params":[{"value":{"id" : "00de1be5-f75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf2333", "path" : "/hardcoded/path"}}, {"value":{"value" : "sdfsa", "path" : ""}}, {"more":[{"additional":[{"value":{"id" : "00f41be5-g75b-4072-ba30-c67e4fdf3777", "path" : "/hardcoded/path"}}]}]}]}
```